# Blank screen loader in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have problem with progress bar between two activities. When app loading form one activity to another activity I am getting blank screen for few seconds in my app due to the lazy loading images in the second activity. I want to display the progressbar in that blank screen. How can I do it?

Thanks and Regards,

Bhargav

Answer (score 1):

Start your second activity and launch [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for lazy loading with [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) bounded in it.

See the example [here](http://sirinsevinc.wordpress.com/2010/05/11/118/) or [here](http://android-projects.de/2010/12/08/threading-in-android-apps-wir-entwickeln-einen-zahler/), and check this [question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388142/how-do-i-show-and-then-remove-an-android-progress-dialog)