# Trouble With TabActivity on Frequent Clicking The Tabs

Tags: android

In My application there are 3 tabs for Tab Host which contains activities .
These activities are downloading some images and videos from server.The problem
is when I frequently click the tabs I get force close due to many exceptions. If I solve one
another exception arise. so I want to introduce a progress dialog on tab click so that the user unable to click the other tabs.I tried including progress bar at the starting of onCreate() and onTabChanged() but its no use please help me regard this.

If this information is not eno

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use AsyncTask to show progress bar.And for downloading use a Thread thus allowing the UI to load smoothly.

Check out this link for Progress bar with Async Task [Progress Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388142/how-do-i-show-and-then-remove-an-android-progress-dialog)