# Displaying progress dialog when button clicked

Tags: android, button, progressdialog

I am using the below code in my application.

```
    Button button = new Button(this);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(v.getContext());
                    pd.setTitle("Please wait.......");
                    pd.show();
                    // some task which will take minimum  2 or 3 seconds
                    // e.g. parsing XML file
                    pd.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

I thought according to above code, when i click the button the progress dialog has to be displayed on screen, but its not displaying. Why i don't know.

But if i remove `pd.dismiss()` its displaying, that also after button released only.

If i put **any infinite loop in place of my task** also, its **not displaying progress dialog**.

Is my code correct ? If anybody knows solution to my requirement please reply to this post.

Thanks.

Comment: have you read android dev guide for progress [dialog](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ProgressDialog) ? also, if you look at the right of this page, there are lot's of  questions with this exact problem.

Comment: i saw all those, all are talking about threads and progress dialog box. Everybody posted code with Progress Dialog inside a Thread. I posted here to get solution if anybody tried without AsyncTask. thanks for comment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I show and then remove an android progress dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388142/how-do-i-show-and-then-remove-an-android-progress-dialog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the AsychTask class for just write your code into the inBackground() method and show the progress using onUpdateProgress() and dismiss on onPostExecute()

here is the example links

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: Small doubt, is it possible without AsyncTask ?

Comment: in your case is possible but what happen when progress dialog was shown and it appear on screen before it was dismiss so your task was perform very well but for appearing the progress dialog not getting that much time

Comment: i mentioned in my question ** even i put infinite loop also** before calling `dismiss()` no progress dialog on screen. ok i will try with AsyncTask. anyhow thanks for comment and answer.

Answer (score 1):

AsyncTasks are designed for this purpose. start an asyncTask when the button is clicked, and in preExecute of the asyncTask show the dialog and on PostExecute() of the asyncTask dismiss the dialog. Do the activity which takes time in the background() method.