# how to centering the image and text inside layout android

Tags: android

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_connStatus"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#C5CAE9"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/circle_gr"
    android:gravity="center|left"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

I tried both center but image goes left for me . I want image and text in center inside text view

Comment: have you tried this: https://www.google.de/#q=how+to+hide+progressbar+in+progressdialog+android ?

Comment: I tried but  using custom  progress dialog we can achieve this . I try in progressdialog function

Comment: please provide a part of your code....

Comment: @jesu, write the code in your post.

Comment: I got it by using wrap content in linear layout of both height and width

Answer (score 0):

```
private class UpdateFeedTask extends AsyncTask<MyActivity, Void, Void> {

private ProgressDialog mDialog;

protected void onPreExecute() {
    Log.d(TAG, " pre execute async");
    mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MyActivity.this,"Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);

}

protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... progress) {
    Log.d(TAG, " progress async");     
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(MyActivity... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    Log.d(TAG, " post execute async");
    mDialog.dismiss();
} }
```

Reference - [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388142/how-do-i-show-and-then-remove-an-android-progress-dialog)

Answer (score 0):

I centering the image and text by gravity center and wrap the height and width in text view

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_chatconnectionStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_chatconnectionStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/sandal_color"
            android:drawablePadding="5dp"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/circle_bl"
            android:hint="@string/connection_status"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textColor="@color/blacktext"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
```